# Neovim LSP capabilities not exported in Mason

Tags: lua, neovim, mason, nvim-lspconfig

I am new to Neovim and lua as programming language. I am trying to setup a Neovim as a full complete IDE.
My issue deals with Mason and LSP capabilities. It seems that my LSP server is executing but my configuration is not correctly setup properly. **My point is that the keymapping from my attach table are not applied**
My file setup is the following:

~/.config/nvim/init.lua

~/.config/nvim/lua/jpv/ {init.lua, ...., mason.lua, lsp}

~/.config/nvim/lua/jpv/lsp/ {init.lua, handlers.lua}

I have a file **mason.lua**

```
require("mason").setup({
        ui = {
            icons = {
                package_installed = "✓",
                package_pending = "➜",
                package_uninstalled = "✗"
            }
        }
    })

require("mason-lspconfig").setup_handlers({
  function(server)
    local opts = {
      on_attach = require("jpv.lsp.handlers").on_attach,
      capabilities = require("jpv.lsp.handlers").capabilities,
    }

    if server == "sumneko_lua" then
        print("Inside" .. server)
        local sumneko_opts = require("jpv.lsp.settings.sumneko_lua")
        opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", sumneko_opts, opts)
    end
    if server == "kotlin_language_server" then
      print("Inside" .. server)
      local kotlin_ls = require("jpv.lsp.settings.kotlin_ls")
      opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", kotlin_ls, opts)
    end
    -- print("For server " .. server) 
    -- for key, value in pairs(opts) do
    --   print("Has key ".. key)
    -- end
    require("lspconfig")[server].setup{opts}
  end
  })
```

On the other side I have a lsp folder with an **init.lua**

```
local status_ok, nvm_lsp = pcall(require, "lspconfig")
if not status_ok then
  return
end

require("jpv.lsp.handlers").setup()
require("jpv.mason")
```

Last, my **handlers.lua** is

```
local M = {}

-- TODO: backfill this to template
M.setup = function()
    local signs = {
        { name = "DiagnosticSignError", text = "" },
        { name = "DiagnosticSignWarn", text = "" },
        { name = "DiagnosticSignHint", text = "" },
        { name = "DiagnosticSignInfo", text = "" },
    }

    for _, sign in ipairs(signs) do
        vim.fn.sign_define(sign.name, { texthl = sign.name, text = sign.text, numhl = "" })
    end

    local config = {
        -- disable virtual text
        virtual_text = false,
        -- show signs
        signs = {
            active = signs,
        },
        update_in_insert = true,
        underline = true,
        severity_sort = true,
        float = {
            focusable = false,
            style = "minimal",
            border = "rounded",
            source = "always",
            header = "",
            prefix = "",
        },
    }

    vim.diagnostic.config(config)

    vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/hover"] = vim.lsp.with(vim.lsp.handlers.hover, {
        border = "rounded",
        width = 60,
    })

    vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/signatureHelp"] = vim.lsp.with(vim.lsp.handlers.signature_help, {
        border = "rounded",
        width = 60,
    })
end

local function lsp_highlight_document(client)
    -- Set autocommands conditional on server_capabilities
    local status_ok, illuminate = pcall(require, "illuminate")
    if not status_ok then
    print("RETURNING")
        return
    end
  print("NOT returning")
    illuminate.on_attach(client)
    -- end
end

local function lsp_keymaps(bufnr)
    local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gD", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gd", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "K", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gi", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<C-k>", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>", opts)
    -- vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>rn", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "gr", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>", opts)
    -- vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>ca", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>", opts)
    -- vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>f", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>", opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "[d", '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_prev({ border = "rounded" })<CR>', opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(
        bufnr,
        "n",
        "gl",
        '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float({ border = "rounded" })<CR>',
        opts
    )
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "]d", '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_next({ border = "rounded" })<CR>', opts)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>q", "<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>", opts)
    vim.cmd([[ command! Format execute 'lua vim.lsp.buf.format{async=true}' ]])
  print("Inside keymaps iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
end

M.on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    -- vim.notify(client.name .. " starting...")
    -- TODO: refactor this into a method that checks if string in list
  print("Client is " .. client)
    if client.name == "tsserver" then
        client.resolved_capabilities.document_formatting = false
    end
  print("Assigning keymaps")
    lsp_keymaps(bufnr)
  print("Illuminating document")
    lsp_highlight_document(client)
end

local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()

local status_ok, cmp_nvim_lsp = pcall(require, "cmp_nvim_lsp")
if not status_ok then
    return
end

print("LOOOAADIN")
M.capabilities = cmp_nvim_lsp.update_capabilities(capabilities)

return M
```

Comment: mason is not needed and it makes thing more complicated. You can configure nvim-lsp with only nvim-lspconfig.

Comment: Official documentation states that mason and mason-config should be replaces lsp installer . Why should I avoid mason then ?

Comment: On the other side I am hihgly interested in having an editor adjusted for kotlin, spring and java development. I see that kotlin-language-server does not work as good as the one from coc-kotlin in coc pluhgin. Any idea ?

Comment: what do you mean by official doc? See nvim-lspconfig doc [here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig).

Comment: I have no experience for java and kotlin, so can not comment. But If you prefer less setup, you may try coc.nvim, which works more like out of the box (you do need some config).

Comment: See that https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer

Comment: that is not official doc. It is fine to not using lsp-installer and mason. check my config: https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config

Comment: I was experimenting lsp-installer issues that is why I migrated to mason. On the other side, you know the reason why kotlin-language-server works different from coc to lsp ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248726/discussion-between-jdhao-and-jpv).

Answer (score 0):

Replace setup_handlers with this on your mason.lua file:

```
require("mason-lspconfig").setup_handlers({
 function(server)
      local opts = {
           on_attach = require("jpv.lsp.handlers").on_attach,
           capabilities = require("jpv.lsp.handlers").capabilities,
      }

      require("lspconfig")[server].setup(opts)

      if server == "sumneko_lua" then
           local sumneko_opts = require("jpv.lsp.settings.sumneko_lua")
           -- assuming sumneko_opts return a table
           sumneko_opts["on_attach"] = opts.on_attach
           sumneko_opts["capabilities"] = opts.capabilities
           require("lspconfig")[server].setup(sumneko_opts)
      end
      
 end})
```